# Update child component when parent state is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state

When there is a new update in my parent component, which occur within the `function updateItemValue()` , the `items` state will only get updated in parent. The child component won't get updated in an instance. It only get updated when the `updateItemValue()` get triggered twice.

It's something like:

- 1st round, parent update the items, child didn't receive the update.
- 2nd round, parent update the items, child only receive the update from 1st round

**Parent Component**

```
const SelectItem = () => {
    const { items } = useSelector(state => state.itemsReducer);
    const [ itemUpdate, setItemUpdate ] = useState(false);
    const [ group_id, setGroupId ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        updateItemValue()
    }, [itemUpdate])
     
    function updateItemValue(){
        // original items value
        /*
            [
                {"_id":1, "name":"Item 1", "description":"Item 1 description"},
                {"_id":2, "name":"Item 2", "description":"Item 2 description"},
                {"_id":3, "name":"Item 3", "description":"Item 3 description"}
            ]
        */
    
        // step 3 : now this function get called because the group_id is updated
        items.forEach((item, i) => {
            if (group_id == item.group_id) {
                // step 4 : update the value of items state, add extra data, once this updated, I expect the new items value to be passed to child component
                items[i].extra = true;
            }
        });
    }
    
    // step 2 : update the group_id and set the itemUpdate to true to trigger useEffect
    function selectGroup(group_id){
        setItemUpdate(true)
        setGroupId(group_id)
    }
    
    return(
        <div>
            {/* step 1: select option */}
            <button onClick={() => selectGroup(1)}>Option 1</button>
            <button onClick={() => selectGroup(2)}>Option 2</button>
            {
                items.map((item) => (
                    <ItemCard
                      key={item._id}
                      id={item._id}
                      name={item.name}
                      description={item.description}
                      onClick={(value) => updateSelectedItem(value)}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Child Component**

```
export default function ItemCard({id, name, description, onClick, extra}){
    console.log(extra)  // the value is undefined when selectGroup() 1st triggered from parent
    return (
        <div onClick={() => onClick(id)}>
          <div>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>{description}</p>
            { extra ? '<p>Extra item is required</p>' : null }
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

p/s : the state `items` came from redux state. So the state update at `updateItemValue()` is to add some extra value which I want to use at child component.

Comment: Can you update question to include more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code examples? The "child component" isn't a valid react component. Are we to assume "child component" is `ItemCard`? What is `itemUpdate`? Where is `updateSelectedItem` defined? What is calling `updateItemValue`?

Comment: I have updated my codes.

Comment: I don't know what `items` is, but you are mutating it so the parent component is likely seeing the same object reference and thus doesn't know to rerender. Can you share what `items` is, where it is defined?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry about that. I forgot to include it. Please check the latest update again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating an object reference

```
function updateItemValue(){
  items.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (group_id == item.group_id) {
      items[i].extra = true; // <-- state object mutation!
    }
  });
}
```

## Solution

Looks like you are using Redux since you are using the `useSelector` react hook.

```
const { items } = useSelector(state => state.itemsReducer);
```

I'll assume you have access to a `useDispatch` hook and action to dispatch to update your state as well.

You can likely simplify your component code a bit, and move the update logic to the reducer so stat is correctly updated.

```
const SelectItem = () => {
  const { items } = useSelector((state) => state.itemsReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // step 2: dispatch action to update state via the group_id
  function selectGroup(groupId) {
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_GROUP", groupId });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {/* step 1: select option */}
      <button onClick={() => selectGroup(1)}>Option 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => selectGroup(2)}>Option 2</button>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <ItemCard
          key={item._id}
          id={item._id}
          name={item.name}
          description={item.description}
          onClick={(value) => updateSelectedItem(value)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm going to just guess at the reducer function now, it may be similar to the following.

```
const initialState = {
  items: [],
}

const itemsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    ...

    // step 3: update items array by matching item group id
    case "UPDATE_GROUP":
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.map((item) =>
          item.group_id === action.groupId
            ? {
                ...item,
                extra: true
              }
            : item
        )
      };

    ...

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

## Additional Suggestion

You can also simplify the child component `ItemCard` a bit. Direct attach the click handler and simplify the conditional rendering. Also, I don't know if it was intentional (*I think not*), but you may not want the string literal `"<p>Extra item is required</p>"` rendering.

```
function ItemCard({ name, description, onClick, extra }) {
  return (
    <div onClick={onClick}>
      <div>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{description}</p>
        {extra && <p>Extra item is required</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And update the mapping in the parent. Don't pass an `id` prop, but pass the `item._id` to the `updateSelectedItem` callback.

```
{items.map((item) => (
  <ItemCard
    key={item._id}
    name={item.name}
    description={item.description}
    onClick={() => updateSelectedItem(item._id)}
  />
))}
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation :)